# Why can't i set the values of request.attributes?

Tags: java

```
public class Request {

      String attribute1;
      String attribute2;
      String attribute3;
      String s1 = "attr1 is:"+ attribute1+",  attr2 is: "+attribute2+",  "+"attr3 is: "+attribute3;
      
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + s1 + "]";
    }
}
```

```
package com.test;

public class RequestBuilder {
    private final Request request;
    
    public RequestBuilder() {
        request = new Request();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new RequestBuilder().setAttr1("one").setAttr3("three").buildrequest());
    }
    
    public  Request buildrequest() {
        return request;
    }
    
    public RequestBuilder setAttr1(String attr1) {
        request.attribute1 = attr1;
        return this;
    }
    public RequestBuilder setAttr2(String attr2) {
        request.attribute2 = attr2;
        return this;
    }
    public RequestBuilder setAttr3(String attr3) {
        request.attribute3 = attr3;
        return this;
    }
        
}
```

Output: [attr1 is:null,  attr2 is: null,  attr3 is: null]

I'm trying to create a RequestBuilder class that can dynamically add values to the request body using only setters without any constructors. I was expecting the attr1 and attr3 values to be not null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `s1` is created when the instance of `Request` is created, not when `toString` is called.

Comment: `s1` is assigned a value when you create the `Request` with `new Request()`. At that point all the attribute values are null. It is **not** updated when you set new values in the attributes - Java variables don't work like Excel formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toString method is having issue, you are creating s1 variable which gets initialised when object is created with default values, change your toString method like below, it will work-

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" +  "attr1 is:"+ attribute1+",  attr2 is: "+attribute2+",  "+"attr3 is: "+attribute3 + "]";
}
```

Comment: thanks, It worked. Can you clarify what goes on here. doesn't the s1 belong to the request object i created in builder. Why does it not use the attr values set on the same object? nevermind, s1 already created with null attr values when i created the object. It doesn't recheck the values after. @Karl Got it. thanks.